# How to globally #define a preprocessor variable?

Tags: c++, arduino, g++, global, preprocessor

I'm programming an Arduino sketch in C++. I want the user to be able to `#define`a constant directly in the sketch.ino file which will be needed to compile the code. The Arduino IDE uses a g++ compiler.

Let's assume we have three files:

```
sketch.ino
sketch.h
sketch.cpp
```

In sketch.h I defined

```
#define OPTION_1 0
#define OPTION_2 1
#define OPTION_3 2
#define OPTION_4 3
#define SLOW 0
#define FAST 1
```

In sketch.ino the user then defines MYOPTION:

```
#define MYOPTION OPTION_2
```

In sketch.h I use the variable to define macros:

```
#if MYOPTION == OPTION_1 | MYOPTION == OPTION_2
    #define SPEED FAST
#else
    #define SPEED SLOW
#endif
```

In sketch.cpp I use it to improve time critical code:

```
MyClass::foo() {
    // do something
    #if SPEED == FAST
    // do more
    #if MYOPTION == OPTION_2
    // do something extra
    #endif
    #endif
    #if MYOPTION == OPTION_4
    // do something else
    #endif
    }
```

Unfortunately the definition of MYOPTION doesn't seem to be recognized inside sketch.cpp. Hower sketch.cpp does recognize variables defined in sketch.h. Is there a way to define preprocessor variables globally, so they can be accessed in any file that uses them?

Comment: How good at optimizing is the `g++` compiler you're using? You may want to side-step all this pre-processor junk and let your compiler take care of it, as using a standard `if` with an `enum` could do all of this just as well with a whole lot less mess. It's generally better to use `const` in preference to `#define`.

Comment: @tadman The preprocessor cannot possibly optimize my code. The code is meant to be custom, based on the attached hardware. The options which the user provides decide which parts of a time critical function are needed for that hardware. Because the memory limitation of (in this case) an Arduino Due, it does not make sense to provide several functions.

Comment: That definition of `MYOPTION` looks suspicious with that equals sign.

Comment: @RobertPrévost My bad. It doesn't have the equal sign in the actual code.

Comment: What I mean is code inside an `if (false)` block will be removed by any optimizing compiler. You really only need actual `#ifdef` type blocks if the code within that block won't compile on some platform.

Comment: Getting this to work requires the preprocessor having visibility of all the macro definitions in the right order.   That means sketch.cpp needs to include sketch.h which, in turn, needs to include sketch.ino (after the definitions of `MY_OPTION_2`, etc, but before the `#if`).

Comment: @tadman I'm not confident about that as I don't know much about the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Move the option definitions to a separate file, e.g. options.h. You could also define them in sketch.ino if you like.
- Include options.h in sketch.ino and sketch.h.
- Move all the code that relies on the `MYOPTION` macro from sketch.cpp to sketch.h.
- Define `MYOPTION` in sketch.ino before including sketch.h:

```cpp
#include "options.h"
#define MYOPTION OPTION_2
#include "sketch.h"
```

Here's an example of a popular library that uses this technique:

https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Encoder

It allows the user to configure the use of interrupts from the sketch via the `ENCODER_DO_NOT_USE_INTERRUPTS` and `ENCODER_OPTIMIZE_INTERRUPTS` macros.